Debian で 一般userにsudo権限を付与する要件は何ですか？「CentOS 7」のように「wheel」グループに所属させる方法は？
Debian で 一般userにsudo権限を付与する要件は何ですか？
「さくらのVPS」のOSセットアップ仕様を読むと、「初期状態では、『sakura debian』グループに所属していてsudo グループの権限が与えられている」ように思われるのですが、「wheel」グループは関係ありませんか？
「CentOS 7」では「sudo」を利用したい一般userを「wheel」グループに所属させていたのですが、それは「CentOS」だけの方法ですか？

「「CentOS 7」では「sudo」を利用したい一般userを「wheel」グループに所属させていたのですが、それは「CentOS」だけの方法ですか？」 に関して言えば、/etc/sudoers で %wheel  ALL=(ALL)  ALL  が設定されているからでしょう。

古い記事ですが、"debian wheel" で検索すればそのものずばりなページがヒットします。
Debianにはデフォルトではwheelグループが無い
Wikipedia でも以下の通り説明されています。
ホイール (コンピュータ) - Wikipedia

Debian系のOSはホイールグループと同様の目的のためにsudoというユーザーグループを作成する。

さくら VPS のマニュアルにも、デフォルトユーザーは "sudo" グループに所属しているようなので、これに揃えればよいのではないでしょうか。
